# How to allow port on Firewalld?

Tags: firewalld

I am studying about docker.

I'm using SSH on my local PC(window) to connect to my server PC(ubuntu).

On the server PC, I pulled nginx image from docker hub and I run it with port option.

```
{server}@{server}:~$ docker run -itd --name test -p 32769:80 nginx:latest
```

This is docker process status.

```
{server}@{server}:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND               CREATED          STATUS                PORTS                                         NAMES
687b709f8675   nginx:latest  "/docker-entrypoint.…"   50 minutes ago   Up 50 minutes  0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp, :::32769->80/tcp               test
```

I also check port status by this command

```
{server}@{server}:~$ netstat -ntlp | grep 32769
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32769           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::32769                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

On my local PC, I tried to access server PC's 32769 port. But it didn't work.

On the chrome, I tried to connect "http://{server_ip}:32769/". It failed.

And on the cmd, I tried this command.

```
C:{local_path}>tcping {server_ip} 32769
Probing {server_ip}:32769/tcp - No response - time=2003.578ms
Probing {server_ip}:32769/tcp - No response - time=2007.065ms
```

So I thougth this problem is about firewall and on the server PC, I stop firewalld.

```
{server}@{server}:~$ sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

After stopping firewalld, connection was succeeded.

But here is my question. As I know if I add some options on firewalld to allow connection, connection has to be succeeded. In my case, it didn't work out. Here is my commands to add option on firewalld.

```
{server}@{server}:~$ firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=32769/tcp
{server}@{server}:~$ firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: enp3s0
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports: 32769/tcp
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
source-ports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:  
{server}@{server}:~$ sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

But connection failed. Please help me. I don't want to solve this problem not just by shut down whole firewalld. I want to use firewalld and allow connection to specific port. What is wrong with my commands?